# Библиотеки подключенные к проекту в андроид студио компилируются в class файл единожды при подключении библиотеки?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Во-первых библиотека ASNE есть в jar файле, но при подключении его методы библиотеки в проекте не видны.  Что то не хватает в этом jar..  А если подключить через поиск библиотек из хранилища, она нормально подключается.  Смотрю в какой папке расположилась библиотека.  Она в кэш, открыл jar.  Изменил библиотеку, закрыл архив и в андроид студио в открытом проекте я вижу что код библиотеки изменился.  Запускаю программу и код библиотеки в измененном варианте не срабатывает,  я туда специально логи добавил.  Я взял у одного из метод полностью удалил входные параметры и тут студия пожаловалась то т что исходный код не соответствует class файлу.  Я делаю вывод что библиотека один раз скомпилировалась и всё на этом,  считается что она после подключения не должна изменяться. Правильно ли?  Вроде логично,  зачем каждый раз по новой целую биьлиотеку компилировать. Значит чтобы внести в биьлиотеку изменения ее надо изменить и переподключить.  Верно это?  Если да,  то проблема така : эту  библиотеку, подключив через Add library я не вижу методы в проекте

Comment: Если хотите вносить изменения в библиотеку, нужно подключать ее в виде исходников, тогда она будет собираться каждый раз вместе с проектом

Comment: Я попробую,  но как исходники она не подключается..народ разобраться в чем дело. Как исходники это имеется ввиду как jar библиотека через add library ?

Comment: Проблема с тем что не импортировались классы подключенной jar библиотеки решилась очисткой кэша

Comment: pavlofff, я правильно понимаю, что если библиотека в виде jar лежит в папке libs , то она будет каждый раз компилироваться, когда я запускаю проект ? А если она подключена через зависимости в library dependency , то она скомпилируется единожды ?   Плюс первого варианта в том что можно удобно корректировать библиотеку, а второго в том , что не приходится ждать компиляции библиотеки. Всё правильно сказал ?

Comment: И еще забыл.  когда библиотека лежит в libs еще увеличивается объем проекта . а если подключена вторым способом , то использованы будут только задействованные классы библиотеки . Так ?